# cannot copy in range array

Tags: arrays, excel, shapes, vba

When I try to copy in the range array, I get the runtime error saying "object doesn't support this property or method". The error is shown at the last line of code below, when doing `MyRangeArray(x).Copy`. How can I copy shapes in arrays?

```
'List of PPT Slides to Paste to
  MySlideArray = Array(5, 10)

'List of Excel Ranges to Copy from
MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet23.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 18")), Sheet27.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 18")))

'Loop through Array data
  For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
    'Copy Excel Range
        MyRangeArray(x).Copy
```

Comment: what language?  *blinks*  Is this Excel?  Spreadsheets?

Comment: this is in excel VBA. and i'm trying to copy shapes in excel into powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Sheets(MyRangeArray(x).Parent.Name).Shapes(MyRangeArray(x).Name).Copy
```